# delete HTML 5 localStorage data from javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I know I can create JSON format of data in javascript

```
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.something);
data[0] == "some data";
```

But when i try to delete its not working.

```
delete data[0];
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you expecting it to magically update the string that you originally parsed into the object you modified?

Comment: Or, alternatively, did you want to remove the first element of the array and not delete it? `data.shift();`.

Comment: localStorage.something = JSON.stringify(data); Now localStorage.something changed too.

Answer (score 3):

`delete data[0]` will only delete that item from the `data` array, which is NOT the `localStorage` item (since, as you already know, that item is a string).

You have to save your changes. Also I would suggest using `data.shift()` as per minitech's comment instead of `delete` - `delete` is better for object properties, not array indices.

```
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.something);
data.shift(); // delete data[0] without breaking sequence
localStorage.something = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: Is there any benefit from using `getItem()` and `setItem()` in this case?

Answer (score 2):

After you do:

```
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.something);
```

Then the `data` variable holds an idependent object which from now is completely detached from localStorage (which stores just a String that need to be parsed anyway, not a 'real' object).

If you change it, you need to manually update the local storage like that:

```
localStorage.setItem("something", JSON.stringify(data));
```

As a side note: if you are aiming at older browsers, then make sure you include something like json2.js to make JSON object work everywhere.

Comment: As far as desktop browsers go, if it supports localStorage then it also supports JSON.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. I'm tainted having to work so long with website rendered in quirks mode, in which IE had no problems with localStorage, but couldn't recognize JSON...